TortoiseGit loosing branch name in windows explorer on Windows 11
My IT department surprised me with an upgrade to Windows 11.  Took a while but I have all the tools I used to use working again with one small thorn.
TortoiseGit's Windows Explorer plugin used to list the directory/workspace's current branch title on the explorer page when in a workspace.  It's not there in windows 11.  It was pretty handy to glance up there to see what I'm working with (we work with several branches at a time).  I know it can be found by digging in the folder properties, or the sync dialog, but that's a bit more work than just seeing it on the page.
Any way to get that back?  I've dug through the settings and done a git to googling, but not finding anything pertinent.
Thanks.

This feature has not been removed from TortoiseGit, however, since Windows Explorer has removed the title bar it is not displayed any more.
Workaround: You can also see the current branch, when you open the context menu after the commit command.
